# Playing youtube/vevo videos on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, youtube, youtube-api

I've seen the [Google blog article](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html) explaining the way to embed youtube videos in an iOS app. I've successfully embed videos in my iOS app. BUT, I've seen the WhoSampled app where they are able to play Vevo/youtube videos. Somehow they are able to play those videos and my app is not able to play them. (In my app, there is a blue play circle with a line through it showing that is not playable.)

How do I allow those videos to be playable?

Do I have to setup the youtube link in a specific way or is there a way I need to setup the developer key?

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to get the actual video stream for a given YouTube video instead of the HTML-embedded one. See this project:

https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser

The problem with this approach is that it will likely violate the EULA of YouTube APIs, especially if you are releasing it in a paid application:

> In addition, please remember that attempting to play a YouTube video outside of either the YouTube embedded, custom or chromeless player is strictly prohibited by the API Terms of Service.

(source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications)

Comment: i dont think it mathers the paid part, theu eula says you cannot make money out of showing youtube videos or showing ads in the video.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the iframe embed as opposed to the Flash one.

Comment: can you provide an example ?